# Google Sheets Archive and clear issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
     function CreateCopySheetDaily() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Daily Eligibility'); 
  var range = ss.getDataRange(); 
  var ts = 'Archived_Data'+ new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);

  ss.insertSheet(ts, ss.getSheets().length, {template: templateSheet});
  templateSheet.deleteRows(2, range.getNumRows() - 1);
}
```

This is the code I have been using. It works fine on my original google sheet. When I make a copy to share of my document and try to use this code... I get this error message... **Exception: Those rows are out of bounds. (line 8, file "Code")**  The sheet will archive the information on a separate sheet but won't clear the original response sheet from the form and I get this error code. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, I think that when `range.getNumRows() - 1` is less than or equal to zero, the error of `Exception: Those rows are out of bounds.` occurs because the value of `howMany` of `deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)` is `0` and `-1`. Namely, when the sheet of `Daily Eligibility` has only one row and no row data, such error occurs. So in order to avoid this error, how about the following modification?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified.

#### From:

```
templateSheet.deleteRows(2, range.getNumRows() - 1);
```

#### To:

```
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
if (numRows > 1) {
  templateSheet.deleteRows(2, numRows - 1);
}
```

- In this modified script, when `range.getNumRows()` is more than `1`, `deleteRows` is run.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, when you don't want to modify the script, how about confirming whether the sheet of `Daily Eligibility` has more than 2 rows?

### Reference:

- [deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany)

## Added:

For `I won't have a set number of responses on the 'The Daily Eligibility' sheet. But I need to keep the 1st row and clear the rest of the content.`, please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
templateSheet.deleteRows(2, range.getNumRows() - 1);
```

#### To:

```
templateSheet.getRange(2, 1, templateSheet.getLastRow() - 1, templateSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
```

Comment: I'm still getting the Out of Bound error.... 
  ss.insertSheet(ts, ss.getSheets().length, {template: templateSheet});
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
if (numRows > 1) {
  templateSheet.deleteRows(2, numRows - 1);
}

Comment: I won't have a set number of responses on the 'The Daily Eligibility' sheet. But I need to keep the 1st row and clear the rest of the content.

Comment: @Margaret Berry Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the logic that when the modified script of pattern 1 is used, the error of `I'm still getting the Out of Bound error` occurs. I think that I have to study more. So, from your replying of `I won't have a set number of responses on the 'The Daily Eligibility' sheet. But I need to keep the 1st row and clear the rest of the content.`, I added one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.